# ORA-06575: Package or function BUBBLESORT is in an invalid state

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've written a bubble sort algorithm in Java and I'm trying to get it to run on Oracle 21c and I get **ORA-06575: Package or function BUBBLESORT is in an invalid state**

I'll state below the steps that I took in order to get to this error.

The BubbleSort.java file has this contents

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main() {
        int[] nums = new int[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10000);
        }

        boolean swapped;
        int tmp;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; ++i) {
                if (nums[i - 1] > nums[i]) {
                    tmp = nums[i];
                    nums[i] = nums[i - 1];
                    nums[i - 1] = tmp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        } while (swapped);
    }
}
```

I've loaded it with loadjava and got the following response

```
loading  : class BubbleSort
resolving: class BubbleSort
Classes Loaded: 1
Resources Loaded: 0
Sources Loaded: 0
Published Interfaces: 0
Classes generated: 0
Classes skipped: 0
Synonyms Created: 0
Errors: 0
```

After that I made a procedure using this statement

```
create or replace procedure BubbleSort
  as language java name 'BubbleSort.main()';
/
```

When I try to call it using the `call BubbleSort();` statement, it throws a **ORA-06575: Package or function BUBBLESORT is in an invalid state**

As a first debugging step I looked in `user_errors` and got this

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

What should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method name to something other than `main`:

```java
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED BubbleSortJava AS
public class BubbleSort {
  private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10000;

  public static void sort() {
    int[] nums = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
      nums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10000);
    }

    boolean swapped;
    int tmp;
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (int i = 1; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        if (nums[i - 1] > nums[i]) {
          tmp = nums[i];
          nums[i] = nums[i - 1];
          nums[i - 1] = tmp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
  }
}
/
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE BubbleSort
  as language java name 'BubbleSort.sort()';
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

Shows no errors, and:

```sql
BEGIN
  BubbleSort();
END;
/
```

Works

---

If you want to pass in an array to sort then:

```sql
CREATE TYPE number_list AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

and:

```java
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED BubbleSortJava2 AS
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Array;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

public class BubbleSort2 {
  public static Array sort(Array p_values) throws SQLException
  {
    BigDecimal[] values = (BigDecimal[]) p_values.getArray();

    boolean swapped;
    BigDecimal tmp;
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (int i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
        if (
          values[i - 1] != null
          && (values[i] == null || values[i - 1].compareTo(values[i]) == 1)
        )
        {
          tmp = values[i];
          values[i] = values[i - 1];
          values[i - 1] = tmp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);

    OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
    return conn.createOracleArray("NUMBER_LIST", values);
  }
}
/
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION BubbleSort2(p_values IN number_list) RETURN number_list
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'BubbleSort2.sort(java.sql.Array) return java.sql.Array';
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(BubbleSort2(number_list(3,5,4,2,1)));
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN_VALUE |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SHul5eN7)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I've marked it as an answer to the question. And also thanks for the details of how to use an array, I'm new to Oracle and this really helps.